# WPF how to change label of property from dynamic object in MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, properties

I have a program that when you click the button, it creates a person with random attributes.

[image]

If the content of the label changes with every different object (person) created, how do you define that in true MVVM style? I can't have the viewmodel control the view, right? So i can't

```
label.Content = person.hair_Color;

public class Person() 
    get set hair_Color, get set shirt_color, yadda yadda
```

Because there can be either 1 or an infinite amount of people, how do i dynamically add the content of a label, if i don't know how many there will be?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the actual probem, is there any xaml in there? You can use converters to return a color based on a property's value. Plus, the label's content is meant to be bound in a viewmodel as well.

Comment: assume the labels are wpf xml, and the colors are used as an example, i want to use strings from data. In MVVM, the view and VM are supposed to be uncoupled, so the xml would be <Label Content="{Binding person.hair_Color}/> except, when you add the person via the button, you are adding a new instance of the object, so how does the label know which object it is referencing?

Comment: If you display multiple Person, you need a collection, preferably an ObservableCollection<Person>. Then you'd need to display your persons and the labels in a ListView's ItemTemplate, or some other ItemsControl's child class.

Comment: oooohhhh, i get it now, that explains it, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In 'true MVVM style', you would have something like:

## Views

#### MainView containing:

- A button "Add Person" `<Button Command={Binding AddPerson}`/>
- A list containing some "PersonView" `<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Persons}"/>`

#### PersonView containing:

- A label "Shirt" `<TextBlock Text="{Binding Shirt}"/>`
- A label "Hair" `<TextBlock Text="{Binding Hair}"/>`
- A rectangle (for the example) "ShirtGraphic" `<Rectangle Background="{Binding Shirt, Converter={stringToColorConverter}/>`
- A rectangle "HairGraphic" `<Rectangle Background="{Binding Hair, Converter={stringToColorConverter}/>`

#### StringToColorConverter class, returning a color from a string

## ViewModels

#### MainViewModel containing:

- An observable collection property of PersonViewModel "Persons" `public ObservableCollection<PersonViewModel> Persons { get; set; }`
- A command "AddPerson" `public Command AddPerson { get; set; }`

#### PersonViewModel containing:

- A string property "Shirt" `public string Shirt { get; set; }`
- A string property "Hair" `public string Hair { get; set; }`

This is pretty much just a mockup of what you would actually have, since implementation depends on the framework used, but the idea is here. You bind, you convert, etc.

- It doesn't implement any INotifyPropertyChanged or ICommand
- No DataTemplate is set for the ListBox (to actually display some PersonView)